# Problem on exchangeable events

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory

$\newcommand{\p}{\mathbb{P}}$
$\newcommand{\tsum}{\textstyle{\sum}}$
$\newcommand{\N}{\mathbb{N}}$
**Problem:**

Let $\left(A_{k}\right)_{k\geq1}$ be any infinite sequence of exchangeable
event, i.e., for every $l\geq1$ one can claim that the probability
$\p\left(A_{i_{1}},\cdots,A_{i_{l}}\right)$, i.e., for every
$l\geq1$ one can claim that the probability $\p\left(A_{i_{1},}\cdots,A_{i_{l}}\right)\left(=p_{l}\right)$
does not depend on choice of the indices $1\leq i_{1}<\cdots<i_{l}$.
Prove that in any such situation one has 
\begin{align*}
\p(\liminf A_{n}) & =\p\left(\cap_{k=1}^{\infty}A_{k}\right)=\lim_{l\rightarrow\infty}p_{l}\\
\p(\limsup A) & =\p\left(\cup_{k=1}^{\infty}A_{k}\right)=\tsum_{k=1}^{n}\tbinom{n}{k}\left(-1\right)^{k+1}p_{k}
\end{align*}

**Attempt:** (I am not sure if i did it correctly. I really appreciate if someone can take a look)

(1). For any $l\in\N,$ we have 
\begin{align}
\p(\cap_{k\geq l}^{\infty}A_{k}) & =\p(\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\cap_{k\geq l}^{l+n-1}A_{k})\\
 & =\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\p(\cap_{k\geq l}^{l+n-1}A_{k})\\
\mbox{by exchangeability} & =\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\p(\cap_{k=1}^{n}A_{k})\\
 & =\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}p_{n}
\end{align}
Since the argument holds for arbitrary $l$, we take $l\rightarrow\infty$
and get 
\begin{align}
\p(\liminf A_{k}) & =\p(\cup_{n=1}^{\infty}\cap_{k\geq n}A_{k})\\
 & =\lim_{l\rightarrow\infty}\p(\cap_{k\geq l}A_{k})\\
 & =\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\p(\cap_{k=1}^{n}A_{k})\\
 & =\p\left(\cap_{k=1}^{\infty}A_{k}\right)\\
 & =\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}p_{n}
\end{align}
as desired.

(2). Similarly, for any $l\geq0,$ we have 
\begin{align}
\p\left(\cup_{k\geq l}A_{k}\right) & =\p(\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\cup_{k=l}^{l+n-1}A_{k})\\
 & =\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\p(\cup_{k=l}^{l+n-1}A_{k})\\
\mbox{by exchangeablity} & =\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\p(\cup_{k=1}^{n}A_{k})
\end{align}
Take limit $l\rightarrow\infty,$ we have 
\begin{align}
\lim_{l\rightarrow\infty}\p(\cup_{k\geq l}A_{k}) & =\p(\limsup A_{n})\\
 & =\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\p(\cup_{k=1}^{n}A_{k})\\
\mbox{by inclusion-exclusion} & =\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{m=1}^{n}(-1)^{m+1}\tbinom{n}{m}p_{m}\\
 & =\p(\cup_{k=1}^{\infty}A_{k})
\end{align}
as desired.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: I am not sure if I solved it correctly..